# rails Query based on has_one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

```
class Hospital
 has_many: invoice_transaction, through: :invoices
 has_many: invoices
end 

class invoice
 belongs_to :hospital
end 

class InvoiceTransaction      
  belongs_to: invoice 
  has_one :hospital, through: :invoice
end 





hospital.invoice_transactions works well
```

Now I want to query `InvoiceTransaction` based on multiple hospital id

something like this

```
InvoiceTransaction.joins(:hospital).find([.array of hospital ids..])
```

but this returns empty records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `where` instead of `find` when you work with `joins`

> where('name_of_the_table.id in (?)', [array of hospital ids])

```
InvoiceTransaction.joins(:hospital).where('hospitals.id in (?)', [array of hospital ids])
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly cleaner syntax,

```
InvoiceTransaction.joins(:hospital).where(hospitals: { id: [array of hospital ids] })
```